# Android HttpUrlConnection cache , how can i refresh?

Tags: android, google-maps, caching, httpurlconnection

Good morning , I'm working on a project of mine Android using Google Map , where every marker is a JSON object .

My problem is simple ....

Activity Activity A calls B to call the POST method of a JSON to a REST web service , and it is saved .
Then the Activity B closes , and A calls the refresh () method to display all the markers present on web services , but the new marker no trace !

I have the same problem with GET , DELETE , SEARCH , methods!

To view the new markers have implemented a button that when pressed calls the refresh () method , and it works well (though it's not what I need ) !

I tried both setUseCache ( false) , set all the headers possible but nothing !

You know you help me? Thank you!

PS: I use HttpUrlConnection for all requests

Comment: after got results in activity B, call Activity A through intent using bundle. In bundle set the results what you got from web service.

Comment: I need to refresh all completely, this is the problem